# SQL - Can this be re factored to improve efficiency?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    `Artist`.`id`,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', `Person`.`first_name`, `Person`.`last_name`, `Person`.`post_nominal_letters`) AS `Artist__name`,
    `Portfolio`.`count`,
    `Archive`.`count`,
    `LatestImage`.`id`
FROM
    `people` as `Person`,
    `artists` as `Artist`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Product`.`artist_id`,
         COUNT(DISTINCT `Product`.`id`) AS `count`
    FROM
        `product_availabilities` AS `ProductAvailability`,
        `products` AS `Product`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `order_details` AS `OrderDetail`
    ON
        `Product`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`product_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `orders` AS `Order`
    ON
        `Order`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`order_id`
    WHERE
        `ProductAvailability`.`id` = `Product`.`product_availability_id`
    AND
        `Product`.`online` = true
    AND
        (`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'For sale')
        OR
            ((`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'Sold') AND (DATEDIFF(now(),`Order`.`order_date`) <= 30))
    GROUP BY
        `Product`.`artist_id`)
AS
    `Portfolio`
ON
    `Artist`.`id` = `Portfolio`.`artist_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Product`.`artist_id`,
         COUNT(DISTINCT `Product`.`id`) AS `count`
    FROM
        `product_availabilities` AS `ProductAvailability`,
        `products` AS `Product`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `order_details` AS `OrderDetail`
    ON
        `Product`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`product_id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `orders` AS `Order`
    ON
        `Order`.`id` = `OrderDetail`.`order_id`
    WHERE
        `ProductAvailability`.`id` = `Product`.`product_availability_id`
    AND
        `Product`.`online` = true
    AND
        (`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'Not for sale')
        OR
            ((`ProductAvailability`.`name` = 'Sold') AND (DATEDIFF(now(),`Order`.`order_date`) >= 30))
    GROUP BY
        `Product`.`artist_id`)
AS
    `Archive`
ON
    `Artist`.`id` = `Archive`.`artist_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Product`.`artist_id`,
        `Product`.`id`
    FROM
        `products` AS `Product`
    WHERE
        `Product`.`online` = true
    ORDER BY
        `Product`.`id` DESC)
AS
    `LatestImage`
ON
    `Artist`.`id` = `LatestImage`.`artist_id`
WHERE
    `Artist`.`person_id` = `Person`.`id`
AND
    `Artist`.`online` = true
GROUP BY
    `Artist`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `Person`.`last_name`, `Person`.`first_name`;
```

Comment: What's the current performance problem like? How many rows per table? What do the tables look like?

Comment: Generally, samples should be minimized to cut out extraneous code. However, that probably isn't possible here. Please post the table schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and [query plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) for the statement.

Comment: you can get wrong results by combining implict and explict joins and implicit joins are a sql antipattern that should never be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of redundancy in some of the querying.  I've created a single sub-query (ArtistSales) the joins the products to availability and then to orders like you had.  I am including only the 'For sale' or 'Sold' elements, but all dates.  By using a SUM( IF() ), we can go through the query ONCE, and get the counts of each type (current vs archive) in one shot.  Then this is used via the left join against all artists that are of type "online".  As I don't have MySQL directly, nor the structures, I'll wait to hear from you on results.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      A.ID,
      CONCAT_WS(' ', Person.first_name, Person.last_name, Person.post_nominal_letters) AS ArtistName,
      ArtistSales.RecentCount,
      ArtistSales.ArchiveCount,
      MAX( IF( prod.Online, prod.ID, 0 ) LatestImage
   from 
      artists A
         JOIN people as Person
            ON a.Person_ID = Person.ID

         LEFT JOIN Products prod
            ON A.ID = prod.artist_id

         LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT A2.id,
                     COUNT( DISTINCT P2.ID ) as DistProducts,
                     SUM( IF( DATEDIFF( now(), O.Order_Date ) <= 30, 1, 0 )) RecentCount,
                     SUM( IF( DATEDIFF( now(), O.Order_Date ) > 30, 1, 0 )) ArchiveCount
                 from
                    Artists A2
                       JOIN Products P2
                          on A1.ID = P2.Artist_ID
                          AND P2.Online
                       JOIN product_availabilities AS PAvail
                          ON P2.Product_Availability_ID = PAvail.ID
                             AND PAvail.name IN( 'For sale', 'Sold' )

                       LEFT JOIN order_details AS OD
                          ON P2.ID = OD.Product_ID
                          LEFT JOIN Orders O
                             ON OD.Order_ID = O.ID
                 where
                    A2.Online ) ArtistSales
             ON A.ID = ArtistSales.Artist_ID
   where
      A.Online
   order by 
      Person.Last_Name,
      Person.FirstName
```